# ngrx and export member error [has no exported member ]

Tags: angular6, ngrx

I am using ngrx but I am getting error as below [ Angular 6 ]

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Angular Activity/NgRxExample/currency-conversion/src/app/actions/amount"'
has no exported member 'AmountChangeAction'.
src/app/app.module.ts(6,9): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Angular Activity/NgRxExample/currency-conversion/src/app/actions/amount"' has no exported member 'AmountChangeAction'.
src/app/reducers/amount.ts(4,58): error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Angular Activity/NgRxExample/currency-conversion/src/app/actions/amount"' has
no exported member 'AmountChangeAction'.
src/app/reducers/amount.ts(7,21): error TS2339: Property 'AMOUNTCHANGE' does not exist on type 'typeof import("C:/Angular Activity/NgRxExample/currency-conversion/src/app/actions/amount")'
```

currency.ts

```
import {Currency} from './../models/currency';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const  CURRENCIESUPDATE  = '[Currency] UpdateAll';
export const  CURRENCIESUPDATED = '[Currency] UpdatedAll';

export class CurrenciesUpdateAction implements Action {
    readonly type =  CURRENCIESUPDATE
}

export class CurrenciesUpdatedAction implements Action {
    readonly type =  CURRENCIESUPDATED
    constructor(public payload: Currency[]) {}
}
```

amount.ts:

```
import {Currency} from './../models/currency';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const  CURRENCIESUPDATE  = '[Currency] UpdateAll';
export const  CURRENCIESUPDATED = '[Currency] UpdatedAll';

export class CurrenciesUpdateAction implements Action {
    readonly type =  CURRENCIESUPDATE
}

export class CurrenciesUpdatedAction implements Action {
    readonly type =  CURRENCIESUPDATED
    constructor(public payload: Currency[]) {}
}
```

Please let me know what is missing from this, I am first time using ngrx so please excuse me if it is very silly.

I am using angular 6.

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code snippets shared, it does indeed look like you don't have a `AmountChangeAction` action.